# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'AngularFireModule' was called

Tags: typescript, firebase, angularfire2, angular5

I am using Firebase as a database for my Angular 5 application.  I am able to build, run, and deploy the project using ng build.  However, when I build using the --prod flag, I get the following error.

Using:

```
ng build --prod
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'FirebaseModule'   Function
>   calls are not supported in decorators but 'AngularFireModule' was
>   called.

I don't understand how to configure the AngularFire module so that it works.

**Firebase.Module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";       // Firebase config stored in environment file

import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2/angularfire2";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "angularfire2/firestore";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),  // Error is here
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  exports: [AngularFireModule, AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFirestoreModule],
  providers: [],
  declarations: []
})
export class FirebaseModule {}
```

**environment.ts (and environment.prod.ts)**

```
export const environment = {
     production: false,
     firebase: {
       apiKey: "...",
       authDomain: "...",
       databaseURL: "...",
       projectId: "...",
       storageBucket: "",
       messagingSenderId: "..."
     }
};
```

**Package Versions**

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "^4.8.1",
```

## AskFirebase

Comment: Had you resolved this problem? I ran into the same problem today with Ionic 3 & Angular 5.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error. The angularfire2 team already fixed this in rc9 and it works perfectly fine right now.
Just update the library using this command

`npm install @angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: its working now both the version u mentioned is correct o just need to close my visual code and open it,then its start working.thank you so uch

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue with Angular 6. It looks like it is a bug with ng-packagr. A comment in the issue report indicates the problem does not occur when executing ngc directly.

https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/767

Comment: I was able to get the AngularFireModule initialized after installing @angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9 but it required changing how the AngularFireModule got initialized. I removed the call to the static method initializeApp and added a provider ... {provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: firebaseOptions}. firebaseOptions is the object that was passed to initializeApp and FirebaseOptionsToken is available from angularfire2 module.

Comment: Hey @scott_Anderson   I don't think the problem gets solved when executed directly. What might be happening is that you have two version of the `ng` installed. The global is used when building "directly" , while the npm will use the local (node_modules) one.    Can you please verify both versions, to check if a version change fixes this ?

TY

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error when `ng build --prod`, and got to solve it by changing the { AngularFireModule } import line from

`import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2/angularfire2";`

to

`import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and mark as solution if it works for me!  I appreciate your help!

Comment: This dosn't fix the issue, it still the same issue

Answer (score -3):

change the build script

from

`ng build --prod`

to

`ng build --prod --base-href=./ -aot=false`

add `-aot=false` to solve, but I think it not the best solution. It should report the bug to angularfire2 developer team.